# jQuery AJAX post, redirect and THEN prepend

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am posting data to a php file, which returns a message. Then I'd like to redirect to a new page and display the message at the top of the new page.

I was thinking of something like this, except that I want to prepend AFTER redirecting.

```
$.post('process.php', {"data": data}, function( message ){
    window.location.pathname = '/';
    $( '#content' ).prepend( message );
});
```

Comment: If you redirect to a new page, how do you want to use Javascript contained in an other page ? If you redirect to a new page, you should PHP to handle this, and pass a parameter to your new location (like '/?ajax_handle=1'. Or take a look to flashdata session.

Comment: You can use JavaScript [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) API to move message to next page

Comment: Does your message data contain only plain string or any html as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use JavaScript [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage) API to save message and display to the page.

```
$.post('process.php', {"data": data}, function( message ){
    localStorage.setItem('message', message); //Store the message
    window.location.pathname = '/';
});
```

Then on next page where redirection made:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#content').prepend(localStorage.getItem('message')); //Display the content if null, nothing will be insert to DOM
});
</script>
```